# Which Bands from LISS III image are to be used for NDVI?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, ndvi

I have some IRS LISS III & IRS P6 IMAGES.

What will be the correct bands to make NDVI image and how can I calculate from the data the amount of vegetation present or the change detection?

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Vesanto on the first lines. However, you should note that the band names start at "2" because on former IRS satellites the band "1" is for panchromatic (removed on IRS P6 because of the LISS IV sensor).

for NDVI, the equation is (NIR-red)/(NIR+red). (Red is used because of absorption by chlorophyll in this wavenlength).

The red is 0.62 - 0.68 µm (second band (named band 3) )

the NIR is 0.77 - 0.86 µm (third band (named band 4) )

The last band is a SWIR band.

Comment: I haven't worked with IRS-P6 data so your answer is better. Although the absorption of chlorophyll is all along the visible spectrum, chlorophyll B just peaks in the red.

Comment: @ Vesanto Thanks for the details. Chlorophyll absorbtion is of course not binary. Both A and B chlorophyll peak between 600 nm and 700nm). They also peak near the blue (between 400 nm and 500 nm), but the quality (signal to noise ration) of the blue band is usually lower (because of the atmosphere) than other bands and absorption in blue is less specific to the vegetation.

Answer (score 3):

LISS III is a camera onboard the IRS-P6 satellite (RESOURCESAT-1).

So the LISS III bands are:
Spectral Band   Wavelength  Resolution
Band 1  0.52 - 0.59 µm  24 m
Band 2  0.62 - 0.68 µm  24 m
Band 3  0.77 - 0.86 µm  24 m
Band 4  1.55 - 1.70 µm  24 m

NDVI = (NIR-VIS)/(NIR+VIS)

Usually for VIS a red band is used due to the best contrast.

So: NDVI = (Band 4 - Band 3)/(Band 4 + Band 3)

NDVI is an indicator of the amount of vegetation present. To get a percentage you would need ground control data and then corrolate your NDVI's to those. Or possibly use some other study to work out the formulas based on similar vegetation. To look at change, take a time series of two images and plot the difference.